# FragmentManager replace vs Add

Tags: android

In my application there is a `FrameLayout` on which I am adding various fragments

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, fargmentTag);
ft.commit();
```

Now it seems when I use the `ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, fargmentTag);` and then in other places call

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fargmentTag);
```

I always get `null`.

However if I use `add` instead of `replace` this problem is fixed but another problem appears that each fragment is added ontop of the other fragment and i can see the other fragments below.

I would prefer to use `replace`, but I need the saved fragment state. Also to be noted I am not using `addToBackStack`.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this and it would work.**

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, fragmentTag);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: what is the difference between commit and commitAllowingStateLoss() and will this work without the addToBackStack portion of the code ?

Comment: The difference is when you want to maintain the state you use commitAllowingStateLoss()[Normally, your state get's lost during orientation change] and to your second question it would work.

Comment: ok. Thanks. Dont have the code, with me but will get it a try.

Comment: @Vinothbabu `commitAllowingStateLoss()` is used when you want to _maintain_ the state?

Comment: @ataulm: yes maintain the state of the app, you normally loose your state of application on orientation changes.

Answer (score 1):

You just basically answered your own question. Use `addToBackStack()`.

Comment: Try it out, but yes it should.

Answer (score -2):

FragmentManager: `fm = getSupportFragmentManager();` `fm.executePendingxxxx`，try it.

Comment: Remember execute after commit